# dar tamaño a ion-datetime y situar texto arriba

Tags: html, ionic, html-tabla

Necesito dar una altura a un ion-datetime, pero no doy con la forma.

Este es el código de mi html:

```
<ion-grid style="margin: 0 auto; width: 70%; border: black solid 1px">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 5px">
        <u>Nueva programación</u>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col style="width: 50%">Día de la semana: </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="width: auto">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Seleccione día</ion-label>
          <ion-select class="myCustomSelect">
            <ion-option value="Diario">Diario</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Lunes">Lunes</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Martes">Martes</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Miercoles">Miércoles</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Jueves">Jueves</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Viernes">Viernes</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Sabado">Sábado</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="Domingo">Domingo</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>Hora: </ion-col>
      <ion-col><ion-item><ion-datetime class="myCustomDateTime" displayFormat="HH:mm" placeholder="{{paramsRecibidos.hora}}:{{paramsRecibidos.minutos}}"></ion-datetime></ion-item></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>Acción: </ion-col>
      <ion-col>{{paramsRecibidos.accion}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>Valor: </ion-col>
      <ion-col>{{paramsRecibidos.valor}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>Modo: </ion-col>
      <ion-col>{{paramsRecibidos.modo}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

y el css que le "intento" aplicar es este:

```
.myCustomDateTime{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: black solid 1px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Con este código me genera la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, el campo del ion-datetime queda muy grande (hablando de la altura). Para corregirlo le he puesto en su css la propiedad height: 20px y también height: 20px !important pero no funciona.

Además de ésto, me gustaría situar el texto (en este caso una hora) en la parte superior del . Para hacer esto he probado la propiedad vertical-align: text-top y top pero ninguna lo sitúa en la parte superior.

¿Hay que utilizar otra propiedad? ¿No se puede hacer más pequeño? ¿No se puede situar el texto en la parte superior?